# Filter Array according to 'id'

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm having array of friendIDS & groupIDS. From this I have to filter matching friend & group with that ID from my other array which contains Friend, Groups.

```
    let friendIDS = ["DW548ADS456", "DSAD86465"]
    let groupIDS = ["RQ13131"]
```

now how to filter my items so that I will have Group & Friend which has above matching IDs

I'm trying it by this way but don't know how to search for matching ID in that filter

```
var items = [Conversation]()

    let friendIDS = ["DW548ADS456", "DSAD86465"]
    let groupIDS = ["RQ13131"]
    self.filtereditems =  self.items.filter {
        $0.groupDetails?.groupID == ""
        $0.user?.userId == ""
    }
```

Conversation class

```
class Conversation {

    //MARK: Properties
    let user: User?
    let groupDetails: GroupDetails?
}


struct User:  JSONDeserializable {

    var userId: String = ""
init(userId: String)
        self.userId = userId
    }

class GroupDetails: NSObject {


    //MARK: Properties
    let groupID: String
    init(groupID: String){
        self.groupID = groupID
}
```

Comment: Can you give a sample data showing what you want to accomplish?

Comment: `return (groupID == $0.groupDetails?.groupID && groupIDS.contains($0.user?.userId)` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right,

```
 struct user {
     var groupID: String
     var userID: String
 }

 let items = [
     user.init(groupID: "RQ13131", userID: "DSAD86465"),
     user.init(groupID: "1", userID: "DW548ADS456"),
     user.init(groupID: "2", userID: "DW548ADS456")
]
 let friendIDS = ["DW548ADS456", "DSAD86465"]
 let groupIDS = ["RQ13131"]

 let filtereditems =  items.filter {
        groupIDS.contains($0.groupID) ||
        friendIDS.contains($0.userID)
    }

print(filtereditems)
```

which prints

> [user(groupID: "RQ13131", userID: "DSAD86465")]

Comment: It will be '||' not '&&' . Also this didnt worked for me. You got the idea.

Comment: also group or user is optional in 'items'

Comment: @Nitesh, if you want me to answer clearly your question, you have to share GroupDetails and User class. Actually you got the point that you should use .contains you can also adapt it the your spesific problem.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I just had to check for optional.